# onInit never happens on Android 4.4.2 when I create new TextToSpeech instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, text-to-speech, android-4.4-kitkat, google-text-to-speech

I tried the same code on `Android 2.3`.it works perfectly. I remember that I already used with `Android 4.0`. 
Now trying the application on a **Nexus 4** and a **Nexus 7** with `Android 4.4.2` onInit method is not called. Someone tell me would know the reasons for this, or suggest other methods of implementation?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recognition, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if(myTTS != null) {
            myTTS.stop();
            myTTS.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
            } else {
                //no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    // setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        // check for successful instantiation
        // if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
        myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);
        // }
        // else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // }
        speak("Sintesi Vocale Attiva");
    }

    private void speak(String speech) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS, "true");
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hashMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the logcat? Have you added logging to check `onActivityResult` is being called? Otherwise the TTS object is not initialised.

Comment: Yes, onActivityResult is called. The TextToSpeech object is initialized, but OnInit isn't called.

Comment: What is the init status? Have you logged that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'init status'? You mean the input parameter of the method? the method is not called

Comment: The code that is commented out - Have you actually checked the `initStatus`? Have you tested it with multiple voice engines selected as your default in the TTS Settings?

Comment: The status is not even occurred because the OnInit method is not invoked. I tried SVOX, but the situation is the same: the method is not invoked. The logcat is this: 
I/TextToSpeech﹕ Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.svox.classic/com.svox.classic.SvoxTtsService}
I/TextToSpeech﹕ Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.classic/com.svox.classic.SvoxTtsService}
And when I try to start the speech:
W/TextToSpeech﹕ speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up

Comment: From the debugger I see that the doInBackground method within subclass SetupConnectionAsyncTask, is not invoked. However, the new instance is created a new AsyncTask object and the execute method is invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved:
I do not know why, but eliminating a call to a method that initiated a AsyncTask, it all worked out. The method was called in onCreateView, and had nothing to do with the TTS, as needed to receive UDP datagrams.

Comment: Great! fixed my issue!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is some issue related to the AsyncTask processing when you are initializing the TTS engine in Android 4.4.2.

If someone else face this issue, I suggest to wait until the onInit method is called with some loop that check out this condition, and then continue with the launching of the AsyncTask processes (even if they are not related to the TTS). That worked for me at least...

Comment: Maybe, the reason is because AsyncTasks on post Honecomb devices are executed secuentially  unlike Donut. It's just a suposition i did after read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score -1):

As a work arround, you can start a timer task to delay the start of your Async Task until after the text to speech is initialized. The timer task should start a runnable which does start your Async Task from UI thread. In my case a delay of one second was fine.